# Why PowerShell shows 'Cannot find symbol' error But VS Code Java Process Console runs it nicely?

Tags: java, powershell, swing, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

***Hello***,

I have written a demo GUI project in java for my university. I use VS code for development works. The codes I wrote for this project runs nicely when I run it using the VS Code Run button. This is the output when I run it in VS Code -

[image]

But when I am trying to execute the same App (Code) from the Windows PowerShell or Linux terminal it shows this error.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening ?

**Thanks in advance.**

**PS: **I have tried running it from different folders but still doesn't work. I have used the package declaration and import correctly for each class files in the repo.

Comment: `javac` is the compiler, not the runtime.

Comment: Yes I know that, but shouldn't 'javac' work in the powershell as expected ? And ain't I suppose to compile first then run the code ?

Comment: add the setting "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" to the launch.json and try again

Comment: I mentioned earlier that it works fine when running from VS Code. But when compiling from outside VS code eg. Cmd.exe it shows the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run java file in terminal, Java extension will automatically compile the packages you import. Like the screenshot showing, turn to the directory red underlined, you'll find `App.class` file as well as `home.class` in folder `mains`.

[image]

But when you use `javac App.java` in external PowerShell, there's no process like the one in VS Code, so first you should compile packages imported:

[image]

Then you can run it successfully.